# Explicitly load related entities within entities

Tags: entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-5

I have object graph like the following:

```
Public ClassA
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<ClassB> ClassB_List { get; set; }
}

Public ClassB
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<ClassC> ClassC_List { get; set; }
}

Public ClassC
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Now what I would like to do is since I have disabled lazy load at the DBContext level, for a given ClassA instance, I would like to load allrelated entities (ClassBList and ClassCList).
I'm able to load the nested collection for ClassB_List using:

```
context.Entry(classA).Collection("ClassB_List").Load();
```

However, I don't know how to then load each child item within ClassB_List for ClassC_List without resorting to something rubbish like this:

```
classA.ClassB_List.ToList().ForEach(c => context.Entry(c).Collection("ClassC_List").Load());
```

Another way I know I found is use eager loading at the context using Include() :

```
var c = context.ClassA_list
                          .Include("ClassB_List.ClassC_List")
                          .ToList();
```

Which is fine for list of ClassA instance if I already had the property included within by DBContext model but I don't often want to do this and just want to use explicitly load.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have used the two ways to eager load:

- Include
- Load

if you want some flexibility you can do something like this:

```
 var c = context.ClassA_list;

 if (IWantTheRelatedTable)
 {
    c = c.Include("ClassB_List.ClassC_List");
 }

 var result = c.ToList();
```

You build an IQueryable, then when it has all the includes you need you execute it.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with explicit loading without using eager loading since I like to load the related entities for a single parent entity rather than a list?